# Able to patch Ingress when specifically provided json in -p arg but not when provided through a variable

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to patch ingress when I specify json like below, I'm able to (all below commands have --dry-run enabled, I know):

```
kubectl patch ing ing-routing '--type=json'  '--patch=[{"op": "add","path": "/spec/rules/0/http/paths/-","value": {"path": "/path/to/patch/service", "backend": {"serviceName": "patch-svc-cip","servicePort": 8443}}}]' --dry-run -o yaml -n namespace
```

But if I try to do it like:

```
value="$(</tmp/ingress-route-patch.json)"
kubectl patch ing ing-routing '--type=json'  '--patch=$value' --dry-run -o yaml -n namespace
```

I get this error: `error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type jsonpatch.Patch`

I have also tried

```
ingressRoute=$(cat /tmp/ingress-routing-patch.json)
kubectl patch ing ing-routing '--type=json'  '--patch=$ingressRoute' --dry-run -o yaml -n namespace
```

&

```
kubectl patch ing ing-routing '--type=json'  '--patch=$(cat /tmp/ingress-routing-patch.json)' --dry-run -o yaml -n namespace
```

&

```
kubectl patch ing ing-routing --type='json'  -p='$(cat /tmp/ingress-routing-patch.json)' --dry-run -o yaml -n namespace
```

but same error came everytime. I need to patch it from a file since we need to add endpoints dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `"` in `-p` flag instead of `'`.
Following works for me

```
kubectl patch ing ing-routine --type='json'  -p="$(cat /tmp/ingress-routing-patch.json)" --dry-run -o yaml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. I actually tried `kubectl patch ing ing-routine --type='json'  -p='"$(cat /tmp/ingress-routing-patch.json)"' --dry-run -o yaml` but turns out I just had to use double quotes only.